# Rails3: Simple routing problem between view and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**Relevent codes**

routes.rb

```
Waterloop3::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :submissions
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

submission_controller.rb
- Contains an action called sort_by_category_academic
- Lists all the submissions with a category, academic.

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  def sort_by_category_academic
    @submissions = Submission.find(:all, 
    :conditions=>["category = academic" ])
  end
end
```

index.html.erb
- Clicking on a link call "Academic" brings the user to "submissions/sort_by_category_academic"

```
<%= link_to 'Academic', :controller => "submission", :action => "sort_by_category_academic" %>
```

**Some weird behaviours worth noting.**

In routes.rb, move "  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'  " above "   resources :submissions  " like below.

```
Waterloop3::Application.routes.draw do
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))' 
   resources :submissions
end
```

When I did this, at least submission was routed to academic perfectly.
However, now the submission page was all acting up. I couldn't put any new entries with this change.
The issue seems to have been with routing priority which I don't quite know about.
If anyone else knows the reason why this fixed the problem, I would love to hear the explanation.
RoR is still quite myserious to me.

**My question**

I thought this would do the job.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

But I keep getting this error when I click on the link, Academic.

**Routing Error**

```
No route matches "/submission/sort_by_category_academic"
```

Any idea how to get around this problem?

---

EDIT

Find action in submissions_controller.rb

```
  def find
    @submissions = Submission.find(:all, 
    :conditions=>["title = ? OR description = ?", params[:search_string], params[:search_string]])
  end
```

Find text field in index.html.erb

```
<%form_tag "/submissions/find" do%>
<%=text_field_tag :search_string%>
<%=submit_tag "Search"%>
<%end%>
```

So FIND is suppose to take in search_string and go through all the submissions that match title or description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
resources :submissions do
    collection do 
        get :sort_by_category_academic
    end
 end
```

And you can probably remove the default route at the bottom

--edit----

```
sort_by_category_academic_submissions GET    /submissions/sort_by_category_academic(.:format)
```

should produce that

the you should just call

```
<%= link_to('Academic', sort_by_category_academic_submissions_path) %>
```

Do you still have the default match at the top..

mine looks like this:  order is important...

```
sort_by_category_academic_submissions GET    /submissions/sort_by_category_academic(.:format) {:action=>"sort_by_category_academic", :controller=>"submissions"}
                          submissions GET    /submissions(.:format)                           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"submissions"}
                                      POST   /submissions(.:format)                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"submissions"}
                       new_submission GET    /submissions/new(.:format)                       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"submissions"}
                      edit_submission GET    /submissions/:id/edit(.:format)                  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"submissions"}
                           submission GET    /submissions/:id(.:format)                       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"submissions"}
                                      PUT    /submissions/:id(.:format)                       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"submissions"}
                                      DELETE /submissions/:id(.:format)                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"submissions"}
```

with this routes..

```
WaterLoop::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :submissions do
    collection do 
      get :sort_by_category_academic
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: I actually use that one for another action called, "find" which is used for search. Its implementation is almost exactly same as "sort_by_category_academic", and it works while "sort_by_category_academic" doesn't. But I'll try this out.

Comment: well you can keep adjusting, and just run rake routes  to see the resulting routes that are generated.

Comment: I have this now "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SubmissionsController#show  Couldn't find Submission with ID=academic"

Comment: I get "undefined local variable or method `sort_by_category_academic_submissions_path' " when I try to populate /submissions now.

Comment: posted it under another answer

Comment: Which version of rails3 (3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3) ?

Comment: could you post the new contents of your config/routes.rb   I am trying to figure out why the GET is at the bottom and doesn't appear to be named   Also you should edit the answer below so the routes get formatted as code.

Comment: post :find worked!!! wow. Thank you so much. I struggled with this problem for last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Rails>cd waterloop3

C:\Rails\Waterloop3>rake routes
(in C:/Rails/Waterloop3)
     submissions GET    /submissions(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"submissions"}
                 POST   /submissions(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"submissions"}
  new_submission GET    /submissions/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"submissions"}
 edit_submission GET    /submissions/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"submissions"}
      submission GET    /submissions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"submissions"}
                 PUT    /submissions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"submissions"}
                 DELETE /submissions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"submissions"}
submissions_find GET    /submissions/find(.:format)     {:controller=>"submissions", :action=>"find"}
         GET    /submissions/sort_by_category_academic(.:format) {:controller=>"submissions", :action=>"academic"}

C:\Rails\Waterloop3>

Answer (score 0):

Routes.rb

Waterloop3::Application.routes.draw do

resources :submissions 
  get "submissions/find"
  get "submissions/sort_by_category_academic(.:format)"

end

Comment: Look at my answer above  Copy my routes exactly.  Use the :sort_by_category_academic as opposed to the quoting/string method..

Comment: Genius! It works now. Thank you very much. What should I write for my find action in the routes? I removed the old routes line. My find action takes in a string.

Comment: what does find do?  Does it work on all objects or one object?    adding get :find  to the collection would call the find method on the controller. Do you expect to call it from a form  then you can use post :find ..